transmission-daemon times out when launched by systemd
I have been running transmission-daemon without problems for weeks since setting a new VPS running Ubuntu 24.04.1. Within the last 24 hours, I noticed the service was no longer responding. When I checked journalctl, it said the service failed with a timeout.
× transmission-daemon.service - Transmission BitTorrent Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Sun 2024-09-22 23:46:37 MDT; 3min 51s ago
    Process: 2621 ExecStart=/usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-level=error (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 2621 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 374ms

Sep 22 23:45:07 arrakis.hrethgir.org systemd[1]: Starting transmission-daemon.service - Transmission BitTorrent Daemon...
Sep 22 23:46:37 arrakis.hrethgir.org systemd[1]: transmission-daemon.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
Sep 22 23:46:37 arrakis.hrethgir.org transmission-daemon[2621]: Closing transmission session... done.
Sep 22 23:46:37 arrakis.hrethgir.org systemd[1]: transmission-daemon.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Sep 22 23:46:37 arrakis.hrethgir.org systemd[1]: Failed to start transmission-daemon.service - Transmission BitTorrent Daemon.

Here is the content of /usr/lib/systems/system/transmission-daemon.service:
[Unit]
Description=Transmission BitTorrent Daemon
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=debian-transmission
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-level=error
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
NoNewPrivileges=true
MemoryDenyWriteExecute=true
ProtectSystem=true
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

If I launch transmission-daemon from the command line with the same options, it works fine.
sudo -u debian-transmission /usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-level=error

I know the configuration file works because when I run the daemon manually, I can connect to it, and add and manage torrents. But trying to run it via systemd fails. Any ideas?

Since transmission needs sudo for your user, systemd might not be able to start it - it doesn't use sudo but tries to start it as "debian-transmission" user

Passing the flag "-u debian-transmission" should be simulating this process and running as this user. When it is run manually this way, it creates files as this user.

This iscnown issue. Discussed on https://github.com/transmission/transmission/issues/6991
Steps to fix:
systemctl edit --full transmission-daemon.service

And change Type=notify to Type=simple

The conversation seems to point to a fault in AppArmor, and not Transmission-Daemon. It seems that for some people, transmission-daemon package doesn't work out of the box for Ubuntu 24.04, and maybe the AppArmor/libsystemd update is why is it worked for me until a recently. Thanks for linking to the issue. For some reason, I couldn't find it on the GitHub.

thank you, you saved me a lot of time

So I'm getting the same using the RiscV arch on a visionfive2.  Assumed it was something specific to Riscv but I guess not.
I also noticed that during the timeout of systemd, I could goto localhost:9091 and see the webpage, and get a list (empty) of torrents using transmission-remote.
I changed the .service file from 'Type=notify' to 'Type=exec' and it seems to function correctly.  (I guess missing whatever sd-notify was doing).
Is there a compile flag to enable notify for systemd thats perhaps missing?
